# Create listener for Azure service bus topic

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azureservicebus

I have a WCF service written in .NetFramework 4.6 , this service handles all the CRUD operations being done on customer. I have Microservice  written in .Net core 3.0 . the WCF service is sending messages into Azure service bus topic once new customer is being created . I want to implement a listener that listens on the messages being sent to the queue and sync it to another Database.
I wanted to inject the code of the listener into the microservice as it holds the APIs that sync data into the other database.
I am wondering should I add a project into the microservice that is an Azure function listens on that service bus topic and inside it call the service layer from the same service to send the data to the other DB or I can directly inject the listener code in the Microservice business layer and start the Listener to be up and running through the life time of the microservice, I am just concerned about the scalability and maintabiltiy  of this solution. i investigated but couldn't decide which solution i should use as I never used service bus before.

I tried to create the Azure function and the trigger of it is queue messages but the problem is the Azure function force you to chose only one topic to subscribe on and currently I have CreateCustomer topic but in the future i will have also topic for updatedCustomer  and deletedCustomer . I am woundering if i should have Azure function for each topic but i am afraid that the microservice is going to convert into Nonathletic in that case .
Regarding the other solution of injecting the code of the listener directly and write code that activate the listener in the life time of the application sounds like it will increase the complexity of the code and make it hard to be maintained

Answer (score 0):

- **First approach** is to create an Azure Function that listens on the Service Bus topic and calls the service layer from the same service to send the data to the other database. However, you mentioned that you have multiple topics, and creating an Azure Function for each topic may not be scalable.

Using this reference, we can send to the [individual function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

```
[ServiceBusTrigger(
                topicName: "%MyServiceBus.Topic%",
                subscriptionName: "%MyServiceBus.Subscription%",
                Connection = "MyServiceBus.Connection")]
```

**host.json:**

```
{  
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Topic": "TestEvent",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Subscription": "Appl1cation1",
    "PriorityBoardingFare.Connection": "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxx.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxxxd;SharedAccessKey=adasdasdasdasdasdasd"    
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 21094
  }
}
```

[image]

- **Second approach** is to directly inject the listener code in the Microservice business layer and start the listener to be up and running through the lifetime of the microservice. This approach may increase the complexity of the code and make it harder to maintain.

In the context of scalability and maintainability, it is recommended to use a separate project for the listener code and use a message processing framework such as MassTransit.

**Reference:**

- [Azure Service Bus Quick Start · MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/quick-starts/azure-service-bus).